# A question about univalent functions

Tags: complex-analysis

The following question was part of my complex analysis assignment and I was unable to solve it. Possibility of discussion of assignment is bleak so I am putting it here for help.

> Suppose that f(z) is analytic at $z_0$ with $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ . Show that there exist neighbourhood U and V of $z_0$ and $f(z_0)$, respectively ,such that f(z) is a univalent mapping from U onto V.

I chose a ball $B(z_0 , \epsilon)$ , also in  some neighbourhood of $z_0$ , let $U$, $f$ is 1-1. I need help in showing that $V$ exists.

Can you please help with that?

Comment: If you already found a neighborhood $U$ on which $f$ is 1-1 then you can simply define $V= f(U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @MartinR noted in the comments to the question, once you have $U$, it is easy to find $V$: just take $V=f(U)$.
The difficult part is to find $U$ on which $f$ is univalent.

One way to prove the result is to use the inverse function theorem from calculus in two variables:
if one writes (identifying complex numbers with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$) $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $f'(z_0)\neq0$ implies
$$\text{Jac}\left(\begin{pmatrix}u(x,y)\\v(x,y)\end{pmatrix}\right)_{(x_0,y_0)}=\det\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_xu&\partial_yu \\
\partial_xv&\partial_yv
\end{pmatrix}=\partial_xu\partial_yv-\partial_xv\partial_yu\overset{C-R}{=}(\partial_xu)^2+(\partial_xv)^2=|f'(z_0)|^2\neq 0$$
Thus $f(z)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ is $1-1$ on a small enough disc centered at $z_0$. The result follows taking as $U$ such disk and $V=f(U)$.

Another way is by means of Rouche's theorem:
suppose wlog $z_0=0,f'(z_0)=1, f(z_0)=0$.  By continuity, there's a disk $D(0,r)$ on which $\frac32 |z|\ge|f|\ge \frac12|z|$.
Thus, for $w:|w|<\frac r3$, we have that $$|f(z)-f(w)-f(z)|=|f(w)|\le \frac32|w|<\frac r2\le\min_{\partial D}|f|$$ By Rouche, $f(z)-f(w)$ and $f(z)$ have the same number of zeros on $D$, $1$.
Thus
$f$ is $1-1$ on $D(0,\frac r3)$.

The result follows taking $U=D(0,\frac r3)$, $V=f(U)$.